# What is the smallest positive period of $\cos(ax+\frac{2\pi}{3})$ for $-\pi \le x \le \pi$

Tags: trigonometry

This function has period $\frac{2\pi}{|a|}$, however i'm not sure how to find the **smallest** period.

We also know that $\cos(ax+\frac{2\pi}{3}+T)=\cos(ax + \frac{2\pi}{3}).$  Solving for T would just give

$T = \arccos \left(\cos \left(ax+\frac{2\pi }{3}\right)\right)+2\pi n-ax-\frac{2\pi }{3}$. Which does not seem to simplify.

Comment: I am confused with the condition $-\pi<x<\pi$. What if $a$ is so small that the function (which otherwise does have the (smallest) period $\frac{2\pi}{|a|}$) doesn't even manage to have *one* period in this interval?

Comment: I believe, question relates to strict definition of period. Let define it: $f:D\to E$ has period $T>0$ if and only if $f(x+T)=f(x)$ for all cases when both $x$ and $x+T$ are in $D$. Then at $a=0$ there are no minimum period (every positive number is period), at $|a|\geq 1$ minimum period is $\frac{2\pi}{|a|}$. As for $0<|a|<1$ there are no minimum period: every number greater than $2\pi$ is period because there are no possible cases for definition, but $2\pi$ is not period because $f(-\pi)\neq f(\pi)$ at such $a$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop See the comments following my answer.  I believe that the OP (i.e. original poster) misinterpreted the intent of the problem composer.  I think that the intention was that once $~\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{|a|}~$ was computed, this period had to be effective against any value of $x$ in the interval $-\pi \leq x \leq \pi.$  I think that the problem composer merely intended that you must show that for all $x$ in this range, the function is periodic, and the minimum period is $~\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{|a|}.$

Comment: @StinkingBishop So, if $a = (1/10)$, then I think that the problem composer would then intend that for all $x$ such that $-\pi \leq x \leq \pi, ~ \cos(1/10[x + 20\pi] + 2\pi/3) = \cos(1/10[x] + 2\pi/3).$

Answer (score 1):

> What is the smallest positive period of $cos(ax+\frac{2\pi}{3})$ for $-\pi \le x \le \pi$

First, consider the alternative problem of determining the
smallest positive period of $\cos(ax)$.  As you determined, the period is $\displaystyle ~\frac{2\pi}{|a|}$.

One way of visualizing this is to imagine that $a = 5.$  Then, the normal graph of $y = \cos(x)$ is *horizontally* compressed, so that for $x$ in the range of $(0)$ through $2\pi$, you have $(5)$ periods, instead of $(1)$.

So, this intuitively justifies the idea behind having a period of $~\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{|a|},$ for this alternative problem.

---

Now, consider the intuitive difference between the two functions $y = \cos(x)$ and $y = \sin(x)$, both of which have a period of $(2\pi)$.

The sine function is nothing more than the cosine function, shifted $(\pi/2)$ to the right.  This idea is easily confirmed analytically, by reasoning that

$\sin(\pi/2 + x) = \sin(\pi/2)\cos(x) + \sin(x)\cos(\pi/2) = \cos(x).$

So, when comparing the sine and cosine functions, you see that the horizontal shift of the graph does not alter the period.

Intuitively, the same thing is at work with the assigned problem.  The period of the $f(x) = \cos(ax + 2\pi/3)$ function can not in any way be different from the period of $g(x) = \cos(ax)$, because the only difference between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is a horizontal shift.

---

**Edit**
If you want, you can use the more formal approach of assuming that there is some period smaller $P$ than $\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{|a|}$ that applies to the function $f(x) = \cos[ax + (2\pi/3)].$

Then, you could use this to prove that if $g(x) = \cos(ax)$, that you must have that $g(x + P) = g(x).$  This would yield a contradiction, because you had already determined that the smallest period of $g(x) = \cos(ax)$ is $\displaystyle ~\frac{2\pi}{|a|}.$

Intuitively, this strikes me as overkill, because of the intuitive idea that a horizontal shift in the graph can not affect the period of the function.

---

**Addendum**
I misread the OP's (i.e. original poster's) intent.

It is also desired to show that $~\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{|a|}$ is the minimum period.

Suppose that there is some period $p < ~\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{|a|}.$

This implies that $f(x) = \cos(ax + 2\pi/3)$ has a period $p$

Let $y = ax + 2\pi/3,~$ and let $g(y) = \cos(y).$

Then $g(y) = f(x).$

So $\cos(ax + 2\pi/3) = \cos(y)$.

Under the assumption that $f(x)$ has a period $p < ~\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{|a|}$, you have that

$f(x + p) = f(x).$

This implies that $\cos[a(x + p) + (2\pi/3)] = \cos[ax + (2\pi/3)].$

This implies that $g(y) = \cos[ax + (2\pi/3)] = \cos[ax + 2(\pi/3) + ap] = g[y + (ap)].$

This yields a contradiction, because $g(y)$, which is the cosine function, is known to have a period of $(2\pi)$, and by assumption, you have that $|ap| < (2\pi).$

So, the assumption that $f(x)$ has a period less than $~\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{|a|}$ has led to the contradiction that the period of the cosine function $g(y) = \cos(y)$ has a period of $(ap)$, where $|ap| < (2\pi).$

Comment: Thanks, although your answer just proves that there is a small period, however my question was how can i find this specific value of that period in the interval

Comment: @CCZ23 See the addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Sorry, i still think you have misunderstood. The question is to find the minimum period in $[-\pi, \pi]$. For example, which value of $a$ produces the minimum period in this interval. Is the minimum period $\frac{2\pi}{4}$ or $\frac{\pi}{3}$... etc

Comment: @CCZ23 I am interpreting the question differently.  As I see it, the question is asking for the minimum value of the period $p$, regardless of its size, such that for all $x$ where $-\pi \leq x \leq \pi,$ you have that $\cos[a(x + p) + (2\pi/3)] = \cos[ax + (2\pi/3)].$  The minimum period of this function is $~\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{|a|}$, which I believe is what is being asked for.  Suppose (for example) that $a = (1/10)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: @CCZ23 Then, the period of the function would be $(20\pi)$, which means that under your interpretation of the problem, there is no value of $p$ in the range $[-\pi,\pi]$ that will serve as the period of the function.  So, I do not think that your interpretation of the problem represents the intent of the problem composer.